# Calculate the maximum possible area of the quadrilateral (functions and derivatives)

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

The total area $A(x)$ in $m^2$ of a quadrilateral is given by:
$$A(x)= 2 \sqrt{ x^2 -16} +\frac 14\sqrt{68x^2-x^4-256},\;\;    (4 < x < 8)$$

How do I calculate the maximum possible area of the quadrilateral.

As i have understood I need to find the derivative of A(x) then find the stationary points but I am struggling to first find the derivative and then find the stationary points.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If area is a function of $x$, then what does $x$ represent? And what does $m$ have to do with $A(x)$ (I'm referring to your expression: "The total area A(x)m^2..."

Comment: Please let me know if the formatted edit is now correct.

Comment: The formatted edit is perfect now. The m element I believe is the area as area is calculated in metres squared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your derivative you posted in the comment to the other hint is correct.

Hint: Find the common denominator and add the fractions. The stationary points will occur when the derivative is equal to zero, and the derivative will equal zero only when the numerator is equal to zero. What values of $x$ that are within your range make the numerator zero?

$$\dfrac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2-16}} + \dfrac{136x-4x^3}{8\sqrt{68x^2-x^4-256}} = \dfrac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2-16}} + \dfrac{34x-x^3}{2\sqrt{68x^2-x^4-256}}$$ $$=\dfrac{4x\sqrt{68x^2- x^4-256 }+(34x-x^3)\sqrt{x^2 - 16}}{2\sqrt{x^2 - 16}\sqrt{68x^2 -x^4 - 256}}$$

Clearly, the numerator equals zero when $x=0$. That's because $x = 0$ gives the minimum possible area! But you need the maximum area, and you need the solution such that $4\lt x \lt 8$. Put the numerator equal to zero, in a separate equation, and then solve for $x$.

$$4x\sqrt{68x^2 - x^4 - 256} + (34x - x^3)\sqrt{x^2 - 16} = 0$$ $$\iff 4\sqrt{68x^2 - x^4 - 256} + (34 - x^2)\sqrt{x^2 - 16} = 0$$

Comment: Brilliant that was extremely helpful thank you

Comment: You're very welcome, skeeto!

Comment: When you obtain the solution to $x$, don't forget to plug that value into the original $A(x)$ to find what the maximum area is.

Comment: @amWhy. The solution is not obvious at all ! Cheers.

Comment: @amWhy. Sorry ! I worked with $1/2$ instead of $2$ for the first coefficient. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Use the fact that the derivative of $\sqrt{u(x)} $ is $\frac{u'(x)}{2 \sqrt{u(x)}}$. Apply this to the two parts of the expression. It will probaly look ugly but reducing to same denominator and squaring could help.

I am sure you can take from here.

Comment: I have come up with: 2x/(squarerootx^2-16) + [(136x-4x^3)/8(squareroot68x^2-x^4-256)] but I am still not sure how to then calculate the stationary points from this

Answer (score 0):

$A^{\prime}\left(x\right)=2x\left(x^2-16\right)^{-1/2}+\frac{1}{8}\left(136x-4x^3\right)\left(68x^2-x^4-256\right)^{-1/2}$

$A^{\prime}\left(x\right)=0$ when what?

You should double check $A^{\prime\prime}(x)<0$ for it to be a maximal.